# Jssor - scrollbar show next images

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

We use Jssor program, we have many picture on the left side. 
Have you any idea, how we can show a scrollbar next left side?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to drag scrollbar to scroll slides?
If so, you can reach the goal by manual scripting.

You see, there is an API method '$GoTo'.
You can create your own scrollbar and handle scroll event.

```
<script>
    var jssor_slider = new $JssorSlider(...);
    $('#scrollbar').on('scroll', function(){
        //given a slider with n slides, position can be float value from 0 to n-1
        //check the scrollbar and estimate position to go
        jssor_slider.$GoTo(position);
    });
</script>
```